# best way to duplicate a record in a form

Tags: forms

i'm building forms in wireframes and in one of these forms, the user needs to edit/add goods to a container. On the leftside he has a list of goods, when he clicks on one of them, he has several inputfields regarding that good, accompanied with a cancel and apply-button for when he changes something.
He can do multiple things with this one record (=1 good from the list): edit, delete, duplicate.

Now i was wondering what the best way would be to duplicate that good. When he clicks on that record, he has by default all the inputfields already filled in. When he clicks duplicate, i'm not sure what should happen? Should the inputfield remain the same but should there be some kind of alert that the record has been duplicated? Or should the cancel and apply-button switch from disabled to enabled as means of visual confirmation that he has duplicated that record?

Hope it's clear?
Thank you for advice

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See attached reference.

1) Firstly, I would visually show (I used an arrow, could be any way) - to suggest which good user is viewing/editing in the goods list.

2) On hitting duplicate, not move the user without his permission/knowledge. "Let the user be in control".

3) Slide in a non-intrusive message, mentioning what happened, and also, a way to undo, and viewing the duplicated good quickly.

4) I was not sure about the scenario - but generally while cloning, its good to add a suffix (eg 5 Pallete Cigarettes_clone) in the duplicated good. Needs to provide a way to rename obviously.

[image]

Comment: Hi Amit, sounds like a good fix and you're right, it should be visually clear to the user which good he is currently viewing. I will propose it this way to the client. Thanks!